# Confusion about Hahn-Banach

Tags: functional-analysis, dual-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

I am confused about something related to Hahn-Banach. According to my book, one corollary of H-B is that for $X$ a real or complex normed space, there exists $f \in X'$ such that $\|f\| = 1$ and $f(x) = \|x\|$.

But, is $f$ then linear? Because for the norm we have $f(\alpha x) = \|\alpha x\| = |\alpha|\|x\|$, and $f(x+y) = \|x+y\| \leq \|x\| + \|y\|$, how can this give linearity? Since $X' = B(X,\mathbb{F}) \subseteq L(X,\mathbb{F})$, $f$ should be linear right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the case that $f(x)=\|x\|$ for *every* $x\in X$. The corollary goes like this: Given a particular $x_0\in X$, there exists $f\in X'$ such that $\|f\|=1 $ and $f(x_0)=\|x_0\|$.

Comment: Indeed! So this is no problem for linearity right?

Comment: Excatly. No problem at all.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I already thought it was something small I overlooked but that's cleared up now

Answer (score 2):

The equation $f(x)=\|x\|$ holds for a particular $x$, not for all $x$. $f$ itself depends on the given vector $f$.